# How to open another window in and take user input in Pyqt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI using pyqt5. I have one main window with pushbutton. When i click on pushbutton it should open another window which is having input form to take first name and last name. Below is my code. I am able to open another window but when i am submitting the details on opened window and clicking on Submit Details button, nothing is happening.

Please note, if i directly call Child_ui in Main_Ui then then I am able to see the output form PrintInput function but same is not happening when I converted ui files in class.

Main_ui.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
         MainWindow.resize(299, 148)
         self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
         MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)  

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Register user"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have converted this Qt designed file to class file:

Main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Main_ui import *
from Child import *

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openChild)

    def openChild(self):
        self.child = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = userRegistation()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.child)
        self.child.show()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Main()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is my Child_ui.py qt designer script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ChildWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(284, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")       
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Last Name"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Child.py : Class file of Child_ui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Child_ui import *

class userRegistation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ChildWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.PrintInput)

    def PrintInput(self):
        print (self.lineEdit.text())
        print (self.lineEdit_2.text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_ChildWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(284, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")       
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Last Name"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))


#from Main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
         MainWindow.resize(299, 148)
         self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
         MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)  

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Register user"))

         
#from Child import *
class UserRegistation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ChildWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.PrintInput)

    def PrintInput(self):
        print (self.lineEdit.text())
        print (self.lineEdit_2.text())


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openChild)

    def openChild(self):
#        self.child = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = UserRegistation()                            # <---
#        self.ui.setupUi(self.ui) # (self.child)
#        self.child.show()   
        self.ui.show()                                         # <---
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Main()                                                 # <---
#   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   ui.show()                                                   # <---
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

> .. yes it is working and i was also able to do it this way. I want to do it using two different file. Also I don't want to write logic in Qt designed file because if i do any change in Qt designer then whole script needs to change

**Update**

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from Child import UserRegistation


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openChild)

    def openChild(self):
#        self.child = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = UserRegistation()                            # <---
#        self.ui.setupUi(self.ui) # (self.child)
#        self.child.show()   
        self.ui.show()                                         # <---
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Main()                                                 # <---
#   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   ui.show()                                                   # <---
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Main_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
         MainWindow.resize(299, 148)
         self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
         MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)  

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Register user"))
```

**Child.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Child_ui import Ui_ChildWindow

class UserRegistation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ChildWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.PrintInput)

    def PrintInput(self):
        print (self.lineEdit.text())
        print (self.lineEdit_2.text())
```

**Child_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_ChildWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(284, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 71, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")       
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Last Name"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response.. yes it is working and i was also able to do it this way. I want to do it  using two different file. Also I don't want to write logic in Qt designed file because if i do any change in Qt designer then whole script needs to change. Also is it a standard way of doing? I mean two main window? or should I go with Dialogbox ? what is the standard in such scenario?

Comment: @Nick Thanks it is working. That's what i was looking. One last thing, is it the best way to achieve this solution ? we should open Main window from Mainwindow or we should open a dialogBox or Frame widget etc ?

Comment: @Saurabh   Is it the best way to achieve this solution ? 
This is the most commonly used method.

Comment: ok .. Thanks.. I am beginner so just wanted to check if I am going in right direction. Thanks for your help!! Really appreciate it